# Для роботы AsyncTask нужно нажать два раза на кнопку

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

должен запускаться при нажатии на кнопку. Но для того чтобы он сработал, при запуске программы первый раз, нужно два раза нажать кнопку. Как это исправить?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText editTextCity;
    private  EditText editTextNumber;
    private Spinner spinnerCounties;
    private static boolean doesExist;
    private static int NumberOfDays;
    private static String city;
    private static int id;
    private static String number;

    private static ArrayList<WeatherDay> weatherDays;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        editTextCity = findViewById(R.id.editTextCity);
        editTextNumber=findViewById(R.id.editTextNumber);
        spinnerCounties=findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    }

    public void onClickCheckWeather(View view) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        city = editTextCity.getText().toString().trim();
        id =spinnerCounties.getSelectedItemPosition();
        number=editTextNumber.getText().toString();

        if (!city.isEmpty()&& !number.isEmpty()&&(Integer.parseInt(number)>0 && Integer.parseInt(number)<17)) {
            NumberOfDays=Integer.parseInt(editTextNumber.getText().toString());
            String[] countries={"None","AT","AR","BR","CA","CN","HR","CZ","EG","FR","DE","GR","IT","JP","MX","ME","NL","PL","PT","RU","ES","UA","UK","US"};

            String country=countries[id];

            String query="";
            if (country=="None") {
                query = String.format("https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/forecast/daily?city=%s&key=4e2d6343c40d4652b80a70190ff5ac87", city);
            } else {
                query = String.format("https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/forecast/daily?city=%s&country=%s&key=4e2d6343c40d4652b80a70190ff5ac87", city,country);
            }
            weatherDays=new ArrayList<>();
            DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask(this);
            task.execute(query);






        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "All fields should be filled correctly", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    public static class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            private Context context;
            public DownloadTask(Context context) {
                this.context=context;
            }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            URL url = null;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            try {
                url = new URL(strings[0]);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
                BufferedReader breader = new BufferedReader(reader);
                String line = breader.readLine();
                while (line != null) {
                    result.append(line);
                    line = breader.readLine();
                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (urlConnection != null) {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
            }
            return result.toString();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            try {
                StringBuilder builder=new StringBuilder();
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
                JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
                for(int i=0;i<NumberOfDays;i++) {
                    JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String date=object.getString("datetime");
                    String mintemp = object.getString("min_temp");
                    String maxtemp=object.getString("max_temp");
                    String descr=object.getJSONObject("weather").getString("description");
                    String result = date+",."+mintemp+",."+maxtemp+",."+descr;

                    WeatherDay weatherDay = new WeatherDay(result);

                    weatherDays.add(weatherDay);

                }
                for(WeatherDay weatherDay:weatherDays) {
                    builder.append(weatherDay);
                }

                if (weatherDays.isEmpty()) {
                    doesExist=false;
                } else {
                    doesExist=true;
                }
                if (!doesExist) {

                                    Toast.makeText(context, "This city does not exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, Main2Activity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("city", city);
                    intent.putExtra("number", number);
                    intent.putExtra("country", String.valueOf(id));
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: не вызывается именно `AsyncTask`, или весь `onClick`?

Comment: именно AsyncTask

Comment: То есть вот эта строка `DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();` точно вызывается?

Comment: на экран выводит сообщение "This city does not exist"
поэтому вызывается

Answer (score 2):

Вы неправильно используете AsyncTask и асинхронную задачу вообще.

Оно должно работать так:

1. Запустили задачу
2. Когда-то она, может быть, выполнится.
3. Когда и если она выполнится - исполнить код, требующий результата работы задачи.

Вы же делаете так:

1. Запустить задачу.
2. Заморозить программу пока задача не исполнится (система вообще предложит приложение прибить через 5с)
3. Исполнить код, требующий результата работы программы.
4. Выполнить код, устанавливающий результат работы программы.

---

У вас 2 ошибки:

1. Вызов `get()` у AsyncTask - так делать нельзя, вы заморозите главный поток
2. Исполнение кода, требующего результат запроса не в том порядке.

Сделайте так:

1. Уберите вызов `get()`
2. Весь код, который зависит от работы задачи перенесите в `onPostxecute()`

Comment: можете написать как код должен выглядеть так как я совсем не понимаю

Comment: Код написать не могу. Могу подсказать. Перенесите код после `try-catch` в `onPostExecute`. И уберите вызов `get()`. И сам `try-catch` уберите, оставив только `task.execute(query)`

Comment: а какой контекст для Toast должен быть?(This и getapplicationcontext не работают)

Comment: Сложный вопрос. По хорошему - вам надо его через конструктор в задачу передать. А вообще - либо синглтон из Application класса использовать или вообще AsyncTask не использовать, тк. даже когда оно у вас заработает - оно будет падать по другим причинам в определённым условиях.

Comment: private Context context;
            public DownloadTask(Context context) {
                this.context=context;
            }  ... Toast.makeText(context, "This city does not exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: Так изменил класс но теперь Toast не выводится

Comment: Если не выводится то видимо не выполняется. Добавьте обновленный код в вопрос

Comment: уже изменил код

Comment: Видать список не пуст и у вас другая активити запустилась

Comment: другая активность не запускается просто ничего не происходит

Comment: Может в логах Что то есть?

Comment: В логах вроде чисто. Если вводить данные при которых должен выводиться toast  то при нажатии на кнопку вообще ничего не происходит.

Comment: Попробуйте использовать дебаггер чтобы понять что у вас исполняется, а что нет. Или проставьте вывод в логи чего-то в разных частях кода - в логах будет видно куда исполнение зашло, а куда нет. Без запуска кода не понять в чём у вас проблема. Скорее всего в логике.